# Sending push notifications directly to watchOS 2?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchos-2, watchos

On iOS, we can register for push notifications using the [registerForRemoteNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotifications) method on UIApplication.

I want to create a watchOS 2 app that will work even if my watch is not connected to my phone (but is connected to Wi-Fi). I would like to send push notifications from a server to the watch directly. Is there a way to do this?

If so, what are the equivalent of these methods in a watchOS 2 extension?

```
  application.registerForRemoteNotifications
  application(:, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)
  application(:, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:)
  application(:, didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
```

If not, what are my other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to directly get notification from server on watch. As mentioned  in [Notification Essentials for watch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)

> Apple Watch displays local and remote notifications only if the
>   containing iOS supports them. For information about how to support
>   local and remote notifications in your iOS app, see Local and Remote
>   Notification Programming Guide.

This also mentioned that

> When one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the
>   user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the
>   iPhone or on the Apple Watch

Now there are some scenrio in this, if your phone is active and `notification` arrives, it will be received on phone. but if phone is locked and watch is active and then `notification` arrived it will be displayed on `watch`.

It is also mentioned in [Apple Push Notification Service Doc](http://Apple%20Push%20Notification%20Service) that

> Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is the centerpiece of the
>   remote notifications feature. It is a robust and highly efficient
>   service for propagating information to iOS (and, indirectly, watchOS),
>   tvOS, and OS X devices.

Comment: My iOS app also supports push notifications. Did they mean to say something along the lines of "Apple Watch can only display local and remote notifications when they are sent to an actively connected iOS device?"

Comment: Looks like they key point can be found in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9): notifications can be sent "to iOS (and, **indirectly, watchOS**), tvOS, and OS X devices."

Comment: Yes. watch will display notification when your companion iOS received a notification provided both phone and paired watch is connected via bluetooth. Now there are some scenrio in this, if your phone is active and notification arrives, it will be received on phone. but if phone is locked and watch is active and then notification arrived it will be displayed on watch.

Comment: Can you include the quoted text about how watchOS can only receive indirect notifications so I can accept your answer?

Comment: Thanks for updating, but I specifically meant the quote from [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9): "propagating information to iOS (and, indirectly, watchOS), tvOS, and OS X devices," since that is the *only* quote I've found by Apple which *specifically* mentions you cannot get direct notifications to watchOS.

Comment: Oh  i got that..Please check the updated answer .Thanks